# How to run chef-client on relevant nodes when cookbook is uploaded?

Tags: chef

I want my chef-client to run when something is changed in cookbooks. Is it possible?

I find this "run once in X min" not very optimal. When I change something I want it to be applied immediately so I can notice if something went wrong. Other than that it can run once in say 4 hours just to make sure that config is in good shape.

Answer (score 1):

Very much possible, but not build in.  One options is to put your cookbooks in source control, and then use a CI tool such as Jenkins to trigger a chef-client run using `knife ssh` anytime the cookbook is updated.

Alternately, you can manually run `knife ssh` to run `chef-client` on all machines after you update a cookbook.

There is not a push functionality built into the chef server.

Answer (score 0):

Install a recipe auditing tool such as https://github.com/jbz/knife-audit.  As part of your scripts that upload the cookbook, query the chef server for all nodes that use that recipe and call chef-client on them.